# Attach generic records (like chipset) to a model (motherboard), without creating new record for every single record (motherboard)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm building a PC building app in Ruby on Rails. The app will aim to provide customer with ability to build their own computer

I've run into a problem while laying out the basic data structure. This is what I basically have so far:

```
rails g model manufacturer name:string
rails g model cpu_socket name:string
rails g model cpu_architecture name:string
rails g model cpu_microarchitecture name:string cpu_architecture:references manufacturer:references
rails g model cpu model:string cpu_microarchitecture:references
rails g model motherboard_chipset name:string manufacturer:references
rails g model memory_type name:string
rails g model memory_socket name:string memory_type:references
```

But now things get complicated.
I don't know how to model the motherboard model.

The following should be pseudo-output:

```
---------[snip]---------
- #<Motherboard id: 158679, memory_max_size: 68719476736, nvidia_sli: 3, amd_crossfirex: 4>
  - #<Chipset id: 14, name: 'Intel X99'>
  - #<CpuSocket id: 4, type: 'LGA2011'>
  - #<MemorySocket position: 0, type: '288-pin DDR4 DIMM', max_size: 8589934592, frequency: 2133, ecc: false>
  - #<MemorySocket position: 1, type: '288-pin DDR4 DIMM', max_size: 8589934592, frequency: 2133, ecc: false>
  - #<MemorySocket position: 2, type: '288-pin DDR4 DIMM', max_size: 8589934592, frequency: 2133, ecc: false>
  - #<MemorySocket position: 3, type: '288-pin DDR4 DIMM', max_size: 8589934592, frequency: 2133, ecc: false>
  - #<SataPort position: 0, type: 'SATA 6G'>
  - #<SataPort position: 1, type: 'SATA 6G'>
  - #<SataPort position: 2, type: 'SATA 6G'>
  - #<SataPort position: 3, type: 'SATA 6G'>
  - #<SataPort position: 4, type: 'SATA 6G'>
  - #<SataPort position: 5, type: 'SATA 6G'>
  - #<SataPort position: 6, type: 'SATA 6G'>
  - #<SataPort position: 7, type: 'SATA 6G'>
  - #<PciSlot position: 0, type: 'PCI-E 3.x', speed: 16>
  - #<PciSlot position: 1, type: 'PCI-E 3.x', speed: 16>
  - #<PciSlot position: 2, type: 'PCI-E 3.x', speed: 16>
  - #<PciSlot position: 3, type: 'PCI-E 3.x', speed: 16>
  - #<PciSlot position: 4, type: 'PCI-E 3.x', speed: 4>
...
---------[snip]---------
```

How do I attach these to the `Motherboard`? I believe it's safe to assume there will only be one chipset (therefore `chipset:references`), but what about the `CpuSocket`s, `MemorySocket`s, `SataPort`s and `PciSlot`s? Am I just too scared and this is something even a toddler could answer?

I've made a few apps (<10) in Rails already, but this level of ActiveRecordry is quite new to me.

Of course, I could do it using :json or :hash, but I believe there is a way to do it a little bit more ActiveRecord-ish way...

Answer (score 0):

Up until now you had a one-to-many relationship with your models. With **Motherboard**, you have a many to many relationship.

Given two tables

```
| *motherboard* |  | * sataport * |
| Intel         |  | SATA 6G      |
| AMD           |  | SATA 3G      |
```

If Intel can have Sata 6G and 3G and AMD can also have SATA 6G and 3G, you will have to create a third table called **motherboard_sataport** with

```
| motherboard_id | sataport_id |
| 1              | 2           |
| 1              | 1           |
```

etc.

These are called JoinTables and rails can generate one for you. First create the motherboard table, then the sataport table. Then create a migration using

```
rails g migration CreateJoinTableMotherboardSataport motherboard sataport
```

More info on rails migrations [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#creating-a-join-table) and also go through the different types of associations in rails [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: So this is basically `HABTM`, right? I did work with that just today (I was assigning `Item` a `Category`.) Cool.

Now, what if I need to stick something in that port? Does it mean that instead of using `sataport_id = 1575` I will use `motherboard_sataport.motherboard_id = 2 and motherboard_sataport.sataport_id = 1`?

Then in controller I will do something like `Motherboard.includes(:sataport).all`?